# Handle multiple controllers with buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a menu, containing a lot of buttons. And everytime i click on a button, i want a determined controller to be displayed.

I'm a beginner with AngularJs, i'm not able to find the code for "display the XXXXCtrl"

The missing code is here :

```
app.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showtest = function(key, val) {
        //display testCtrl
    }

    $scope.showCustomers = function(key, val) {
        //display customersCtrl
    }
});
```

see the complete code here : http://plnkr.co/edit/tYFNcYwK8uEJzZGCPQxB?p=preview

At the beginning i had only the `customersCtrl`, who shows the data from `customersCtrl`, so `{{x.titre}}` and the other tags were showing data, but since i added other controllers, i don't know why `{{x.titre}}` is not replaced anymore

Please help, i'm new to angularJs, it's a bit complicated for me :(

Comment: You mean you want to be able to toggle between customers and  the test controller?

Comment: Exactly yes, and eventually other controllers will be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be for your menu controller to contain the the two views you are trying to hide/show.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
  <button href="#" ng-click="showtest()">display testCtrl</button>
  <button href="#" ng-click="showCustomers()">display customersCtrl</button>
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-show="showTestView">...</div>
  <div ng-controller="customersCtrl" ng-show="showCustomerView">...</div> 
</div>
```

Then in your controller, you could do

```
$scope.showtest = function(key, val) {
    $scope.showTestView = true;
}

$scope.showCustomers = function(key, val) {
    $scope.showCustomerView = true;
}
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/k6YScPNv6SmxWuG3GIfv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [$route documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route). There is a good example at the end of the page about switching controllers through route navigation.

You may give special attention to sample's script.js that configure the $routeProvider.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what i want. Cause i don't want to change the url when switching between controllers

Comment: @user You should consider using it so users can bookmark the state of the page

Comment: Maybe it's not a good idea not changing the url, because if the user hits F5 the state would be lost, resulting in poor experience. But to say so, I would need to know more about your context.

Comment: I know, the best is to change url, but in my actual context, i can't do it, too long to explain, thanks for the advice :)